# Обращение к нестатическому методу класса из статического метода

Tags: java

Как обратиться к не статичному методу в одном классе?

```
package teaching;

public class first {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // хочу обратить к методу exanple_ifelse
    }

    public void exanple_ifelse() {
        int b = 10;
        int a = 190;
        if (a == b) {
           System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b);
        } else {
        System.out.println("a != b");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: В чем именно проблема?

Comment: не могу понять как обратиться к методу exanple_ifelse из одного класса из главного метода main

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Стоит сделать метод, к которому хотим обратиться статичным:

```
package teaching;

public class first {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    exanple_ifelse()
    }

    public static void exanple_ifelse() {
        int b = 10;
        int a = 190;
        if (a == b) {
           System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b);
        } else {
        System.out.println("a != b");
        }
    }

}
```

Если же метод должен быть нестатичным,то его можно поместить в конструктор и создать эклезмпляр класса в main методе:

```
package teaching;

public class first {

    first(){
    exanple_ifelse();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    first first = new first();
    }

    public void exanple_ifelse() {
        int b = 10;
        int a = 190;
        if (a == b) {
           System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b);
        } else {
        System.out.println("a != b");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: то, что надо, спасибо, не мог понять как же без отдельного класса обратиться к методу одного класса без статики, теперь понятно, что просто нужно создавать экземпляр того же класса с которого хочешь вызвать не статичный метод. Спасибо

Comment: В Java знаком хорошего тона является написание классов с большой буквы.

Comment: понял, буду знать

Answer (score 6):

Просто создаешь экземпляр этого же класса. Манипуляции с конструктором, как в [этом ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562624/177345), несколько лишние

```
public class First {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        First first = new First();
        first.exanpleIfElse();

        // или для однократного обращения можно сократить.

         new First().exanpleIfElse();
    }

    public void exanpleIfElse() {
        int b = 10;
        int a = 190;
        if (a == b) {
            System.out.println("a=" + a + " b=" + b);
        } else {
            System.out.println("a != b");
        }
    }
}
```

PS: Конвенция языка Java рекомендует писать имена классов с большой буквы, а имена методов с маленькой, сложносоставные имена для обоих сущностей в [CamelCase-стиле](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase), вам тоже рекомендуется придерживаться этих рекомендаций, если не хотите, чтобы другие Java-разработчики смотрели на вас с неодобрением :)

Comment: ок, за наводку про заглавные буквы спасибо